# Is it possible to have colon symbol in directive selector?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Is it possible to have colon symbol in directive selector? This doesn't work

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my:selector]'
})
class MyDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

[see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbadvIHGgcQo8dxz19uz?p=info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular's [Directive Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#metadata-properties) (under *Metadata properties*):

`selector` must be a string.

`selector` may be declared as one of the following:

- `element-name`: select by element name.
- `.class`: select by class name.
- `[attribute]`: select by attribute name.
- `[attribute=value]`: select by attribute name and value.
- `:not(sub_selector)`: select only if the element does not match the sub_selector.
- `selector1, selector2`: select if either selector1 or selector2 matches.

Remember that you are basically passing a CSS selector inside that string (with some exceptions, not every attribute selectors or pseudo selectors works), so because `[attribute:selector]` is not a valid CSS selector, and is not one of the valid alternatives that Angular can understand, it fails.

Comment: Info that it should be valid CSS selector is definitely missing in documentation ;) now it makes sense to me, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Even with valid selector, the result is not always as expected, you can test here how your css selector is parsed by angular compiler : https://ydomenjoud.github.io/angular-selector-parser/