# Directive applied while selector isn't actually a match

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In a larger project, I'm using a component library which contains the following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-item > li > a'
  // Below selector doesn't work well either (does not select the github link)
  // selector: 'bs-navbar-item > a[routerLink]'
  // Below selector seems to target other a's that aren't even remotely inside a bs-navbar-item
  // selector: 'bs-navbar-item:first-child > a'
})
export class NavLinkDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
    console.log('create NavLinkDirective');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('nav-link');
  }

  @HostBinding('class.cursor-pointer') cursorPointer = true;
}
```

However this directive seems to be applied to several elements outside my navbar. I [created a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dt32t6?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter) which demonstrates the issue:

[image: Directive applied to elements that don't match the selector]

Notice that the directive is being applied to the `<a>` tags, even though they're not inside a `bs-navbar-item`. selector: `bs-navbar-item > li > a`

Why is this happening?

Similar questions:

- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708417/8941307) - I would assume that `bs-navbar-item > li > a` would be a valid css-selector and wouldn't cause side-effects...
- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255016/angular-4-directive-selector-to-target-an-element-inside-a-component-only)

Comment: following the link1 in your provided examples there is an explicit piece from angular docs, where they mention what your selector could be so angular would understand it. there is no parent selector with both space and ">" in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gd2bsq?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'bs-navbar-item > li > a',
  standalone: true,
})
export class NavLinkDirective {
  constructor(@Optional() navitem: NavbarItemComponent) {
    this.cursorPointer = !!navitem;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.nav-link')
  @HostBinding('class.cursor-pointer')
  cursorPointer: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector property of directive decorator is not really a CSS selector, only basic CSS.
And the parsing of this selector is really akward.

You cannot target with CSS combinator, only attributes and classes on element.

Your selector is parsed as simply "a".
You can try your selector here : https://ydomenjoud.github.io/angular-selector-parser/?selectors=WyJicy1uYXZiYXItaXRlbSA%2BIGxpID4gYSJd

You can set your selector to "a" , it will work same way. Injecting parent is the best choice to solve your problem.